# zsh alias being overridden somehow

Tags: zsh, osx, ls, alias, oh-my-zsh

I'm on a system running OS X 10.8.5.

I recently tried to alias `ls` to `ls -G -la` command. I opened up `~/.zshrc`, put in the alias, relaunched the terminal, but the change didn't take effect. Upon performing `which ls`, I found out that it's *already* being aliased to `ls -G`.

This isn't behaviour I ever set up. Is there any way to find out where this alias is being set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You tagged the question with `oh-my-zsh`, but did not mention it in the question.

I suspect that [oh-my-zsh is creating its own `ls` alias](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/e5736d39103c59b115270dcf91d31419d3f08130/lib/theme-and-appearance.zsh#L15). If this happens *after* you define your alias, then it will override yours.

You should probably uncomment `DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"` in your `.zshrc`, or put your alias after the line that does `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`.

Answer (score 4):

Create a file called custom.zsh in `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/` and put your aliases in this file. These are loaded last in "oh-my-zsh".

Comment: you mean "in oh my zsh" folder? thx

Answer (score 1):

It is probably in the global system `.zshrc` or equivalent.  You should be able to put:

```
unalias ls
alias ls='ls -G -la'
```

That will delete the original alias and then create your alias

Comment: Just tried that. I get `no such hash table element: ls`

Comment: @atleastthreecharacters So then ls isn't aliased.  What syntax are you using to define your alias?

Comment: I'm using `alias shortcut="full-command-name"`. But I know it's aliased, not just because of the reason I stated in my original question, but also because `ls` actually does display colour-coded results.