# Alias in my .zshrc not working

Tags: zsh

In my `.zshrc`, I have some aliases like in bash.

```
# Usefull aliases
alias rm="rm -i"
alias ls="lsd"
```

I get no errors when starting my terminal, and the `rm` works just fine, but the `ls` does not work, by running `which`, I found out that `ls` is aliased to `ls --color=tty`, not `lsd`. how to I remove the alias and why is it there to begin with?

(I can alias when I am in my terminal, but nothing I know of works in `.zshrc`

Comment: Is your `~/.zshrc` in your `$HOME` folder. Do you have a `$ZDOTDIR` variable set? Does running `zsh` with `zsh -x` give you a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `rm` alias works fine it's obvious that your `.zshrc` is set up correctly.

If you're using `oh-my-zsh`, check this question: [zsh alias being overridden somehow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96071/zsh-alias-being-overridden-somehow?rq=1)

Otherwise, try `cat ~/.zshrc | grep alias` to see all aliases set in your `.zshrc` to make sure there are no other aliases being set.